# Calculate bandwidth per second from bandwidth per month

Tags: webserver, bandwidth

I have a server that handles 20TB of bandwidth per month.

I divided that capacity by the number of seconds in a month.

20000000000000/(30 * 24 * 60 * 60) = 7716049

So by my calculations the bandwidth per second is 7.7MB.

Is that correct?

Can you compute the bandwidth per second from the bandwidth per month like that?

Comment: This is a math question, not a computer question, voting to close.

Comment: You can, but if you are asking "is it reasonable that any arbitrary period of one second duration my server is going to be serving that much?" Probably not. There will be times when it is 1/100 that and corresponding periods when it will be 100x that. You cannot expect constant and consistent client demand.

Comment: What if 20TB is the maximum bandwidth per month? Would 7.7MB be the maximum bandwidth per second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In computing, bandwidth is the bit-rate of available or consumed information capacity expressed typically in metric multiples of bits per second.

From [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(computing))

I think the misunderstanding here is the types of bandwidth.

According to your description 20 TB is your monthly **bandwidth consumption**.

If you convert it to data per second that means that your server uses in average 7.7 MB data per second. But it has nothing to do with your bandwidth capacity (Internet speed)

Answer (score 2):

20TB is not bandwidth, it’s volume. The most likely case is that 20TB data per month is free of (additional) charge. Whether you use it up in a single day or not at all doesn’t matter.

This usage/free data limit is *entirely* unrelated to how your server is connected to the Internet.

All in all, it’s like mobile data limits. Nothing is stopping you from using up the entire monthly quota in a matter of minutes.